# Spring configurartion and Component scan break when trying to create tests

Tags: spring, junit, junit4, spring-framework-beans

I have a Spring app and am trying to setup the tests but I cant get the configuration to work when running mvn test.

The entire thing works perfectly fine on build and when deployed.

The error i'm getting doesn't really (that I can tell) tell me much information.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [c:my\filepath\model\persistence\MyClass.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:454)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:290)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:587)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:305)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:587)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:305)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:325)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:129)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.get(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:165)
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.of(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:638)
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotation.of(MergedAnnotation.java:596)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MergedAnnotationReadingVisitor.visitEnd(MergedAnnotationReadingVisitor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readElementValues(ClassReader.java:2775)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:572)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:400)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:430)
        ... 56 more
```

What could be causing this?

Contents of MyClass...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyClass")
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialversionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id; 
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OUID", insertable=false, updateable=false);
    private Set<AnotherClass> another = new HasSet<AnotherClass>();
    //A bunch of other 'regular' columns and fields
    public Myclass(){}
    //hash method and toString



}
```

Comment: As you said, the stack trace doesn't show that much but, is it possible that you share with us the annotations set in class "c:my\filepath\model\persistence\MyClass.class" ? From the stack trace it seems to be trying to read the first element of an array from an annotation. It's a long shot, I know, but maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Thanks @GustavoFalco i edited with the main contents of that class, it's just an entity. I originally though it was going to be that set, but commenting it out, re-initializing it in the constructor, etc doesn't fix it

Comment: I don't see anything there that could produce that error. Maybe it's a test class that has an annotatiom which expects an array of, at least, one element, and it does not currently has one? That would explain why it happens only while running tests.

Comment: Also, I know it would be tedious but another thing you can do is to put a breakpoint in, let's say:

org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.get(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:165)

And follow the execution until you find out which annotation is trying to use .get(0) with an empty list.

Comment: When I comment out the Entity and Table of that class, the error moves onto the next class annotated with entity and Table in that package. Might be something related to jpa then